# Can i change motherboard and CPU for sony vaio vgn-n250e?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

My laptop model is Sony Vaio vgn-n250e. It has Core 2 Duo 1.73 Ghz cpu. I am getting hopeless performance on it when i use Visual Studio 2010 and Blend along with few other programs running like IE and Firefox. I want to change my processor to i7 or i5. Can i upgrade my cpu on existing motherboard? If motherboard too needs to be changed can anybody tell which motherboard is compatible with VGN-N250e? so i can get better performance because Visual Studio and Blend both are memory hog and it takes minutes even to build and compile my project.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Jason :- Please migrate it. I was really confused whether it belongs to superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the motherbord installed.  Highly unlikley there is another board that fits.

Have you made sure that RAM is sufficient and you have a fast hard drive.  Any other apps sucking resources?  Extra agressive AV scanner? Check disk fragmentation.

Comment: RAM is aleady 2 GB and hard drive is 120 GB. It is the default that shipped with the product. So it has got to be fast. Can you atleast tell me which is the highest processor i can opt for at this stage?

Comment: Unlikley you can change it.  2GB is all you can install so no help there.   The HD is 5400RPM a 7200 RPM or a SSD would help